# Structure variable initialization in short way

Tags: c, struct, initialization, declaration

Trying to initialize structure variable fields with values in short way:

```
typedef struct
{
    int id = 0;
    char* name = "none";
}employee;

employee e = 
{
    .id = 0 ;
    .name = "none" ;
};
```

Got error in `e` initialization:

```
Error    expected ‘}’ before ‘;’ token                                                  
Note     to match this ‘{’                                                              
Error    could not convert ‘{0}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘employee’
```

Why I'm getting error and how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C you may not initialize data members in a structure definition. So you have to write

```
typedef struct
{
    int id;
    char* name;
}employee;
```

Also the separator in the list initialization is comma.

```
employee e = 
{
    .id = 0,
    .name = "none",
};
```

or

```
employee e = 
{
    .id = 0,
    .name = "none"
};
```

Comment: Maybe you should just add that he can set inital value during the definition of a variable of that class

Comment: @DusanTodorovic it is C. No classes.

Comment: Compiler is happy regarding typedef struct
`{
    int id = 0;
    char* name = "none";
}employee;`  But responds with error `could not convert ‘{0, "none"}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘employee’`    to  `employee e = 
{
    .id = 0,
    .name = "none"
};`

Comment: @vico It means that you are compiling the program as a C++ program.

Comment: @0___________ i wanted to type struct. Typo